# Using Two Customized Versions of Zurb's Foundation Framework in one Web Project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, zurb-foundation

My organization has created an ASP.NET Web Forms template with Foundation 4 baked directly into it. The problem is they didn't include all of the wonderful features available (i.e. the block grid). I'd really like to use the block grid, so what would be the best approach of downloading a customized version of Foundation and having it exist with another customized version in the same project?

I have a folder called App_Assets and this is where they demand we put any custom scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certain this is not the answer you're looking for, but [the Zurb Foundation FAQ states](http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/faq.html):

> `6.` How do I use multiple versions of Foundation?
>
> **You don't want to use multiple versions on a single project.** If you
>   are using different versions for different projects, we've got you
>   covered. You can easily use a system like Bundler to define a version
>   (with the gem version). This lets you compile your CSS against
>   whatever version you'd like. If you're using vanilla CSS, you
>   shouldn't have a problem since you aren't compiling against a gem.

(emphasis mine)

So it doesn't look like there is a (supported) way to do this.  Not to say that you won't be able to find a way to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is only one safe way to include foundation 5 in your project.
- include foundation 5 files in your project and set variables $include-html-classes: false;
- use mixins to generate components that you need

for example:

```
@import "foundation/components/block-grid";

.name-o-your-block-grid{
   @mixin block-grid();
}
```

information about all variables you can find in th source:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_block-grid.scss